# How to get reduced learning rate of SGD optimizer in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to reduce learning rate in SGD optimizer of tensorflow2.0,
I used this line of code: `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate, decay=lr_decay, momentum=0.9)`
But I don't know if my learning rate has dropped, how can I get my current learning rate?

Comment: This line of code is wrong: print("lr at iteration {}: {}".format( epoch + 1, model.optimizer._decayed_lr('float32').numpy()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_decayed_lr'
I want to reduce the learning rate in the training process .I just want to get the current learning rate what shoud I do

@OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1e-4, decay=1e-2) 
    @tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
  train_loss(loss)

Comment: It isn't wrong, you need to `.compile()` your model first. You also seem to be using a lot of custom functionality, in an unclear context - it's better to include all relevant code in the original question. See minimal example in my answer

Comment: This is my first time to use stackoverflow Thank you for your answer@OverLordGoldDragon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
print(model.optimizer._decayed_lr('float32').numpy())
```

will do. [`_decayed_lr()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L667) computes decayed learning rate as a function of `iterations` and `decay`. Full example below.

---

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np

ipt = Input((12,))
out = Dense(12)(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile(SGD(1e-4, decay=1e-2), loss='mse')

x = y = np.random.randn(32, 12)  # dummy data
for iteration in range(10):
    model.train_on_batch(x, y)
    print("lr at iteration {}: {}".format(
            iteration + 1, model.optimizer._decayed_lr('float32').numpy()))
```

```
# OUTPUTS
lr at iteration 1: 9.900989971356466e-05
lr at iteration 2: 9.803921420825645e-05
lr at iteration 3: 9.708738070912659e-05
lr at iteration 4: 9.61538462433964e-05
lr at iteration 5: 9.523809421807528e-05
lr at iteration 6: 9.433962259208784e-05
lr at iteration 7: 9.345793660031632e-05
lr at iteration 8: 9.259258513338864e-05
lr at iteration 9: 9.174311708193272e-05
lr at iteration 10: 9.09090886125341e-05
```

Comment: Upvoted. But this does not seem to work with other optimizers e.g. Adam...

Comment: @Khue It should, if you're using `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam`, which differs from `from keras.optimizers import Adam`. Try it

Comment: @Khue I did try it with Adam, and it works neat! Kudos to OverLordGoldDragon !